# Check AD User for Logon Script(s)

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I am attempting to write a powershell script that checks to see if an Active Directory user has any logon scripts.

I can't seem to find any commands that would do anything like that. Does anyone here know a way?

I have looked through all of the commands from `get-command -Module ActiveDirectory` and none of them seem to be of use.

```
Write-Host "Checking for logon scripts."
$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the username"
Write-Host "Checking for logon script."
Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties * #None of this info helps

<#If ($User -eq userWLogonScript) {
  Write-Host "$User'has a logon script"

  }  Else {

  Write-Host "$User' does not have a logon script"

} #>
```

I am looking for something to check AD to see if the user has any logon scripts. Probably involving a function or the if statement's `userWLogonScript`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 places that a logon script can come from:

1. The `scriptPath` attribute on the user's AD account. If this was set, you would see a `ScriptPath` property from `Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties *`. If you don't, that means it is not set.
2. Group Policy applied to the user (via the domain or OU).
3. Group Policy applied to the computer they have logged into (via the domain or OU).

Getting this info from group policy isn't easy. Multiple group policies can apply, so you have to mix them all together to see what the actual policies are that would be applied. You can use [`Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gpresultantsetofpolicy?view=win10-ps) to do this. You give it a user and/or a computer and it will show you all the policies that would be applied.

However, it only supports outputting the results to a file in XML or HTML format. It cannot give you an object that you can examine in-memory. So if you wanted to, you would have to read the file back and parse the information (XML might be easier for that). And it is also very slow.

If you are running this on the computer where the user in question is logged in, you can use [`gpresult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpresult), which seems to run faster (but still not fast). You can save XML or HTML to file, or output to the console, but the console/HTML output is meant to be human readable, not machine readable, so it would be hard to parse. (what you want has the heading "Logon Scripts")

Answer (score 1):

ScriptPath property is what you are looking for

```
Write-Host "Checking for logon scripts."
$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the username"
Write-Host "Checking for logon script."
$ScriptPath = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties Scriptpath | Select ScriptPath


If ($ScriptPath) {
  Write-Host "$User'has a logon script"
  Write-host $ScriptPath

  }  Else {

  Write-Host "$User' does not have a logon script"

}
```